# Can Javascript somehow spy my website?

Tags: javascript

If I were malicious (or malicious and thoughtless) I could add some PHP to websites I'm working (or back-end web applications I'm building) that can send some data I'm not authorised to have to my remote server. There are numerous ways to achieve that.

I was wondering: **can Javascript do something similar**?

For example, is it possible to be spied by using some html/css/javascript web template which will disclose informations from(about) my website - send any kind of information from my website/web app to remote server of malicious developer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes - it is possible. Website analytics, like google analytics does exactly that.

Comment: With javascript , a third party can steal your session cookies , log in as a user , or admin , and get control of your website.

Comment: @camus: However, there are `HTTP-only` cookies that can't be read by javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can send data to other servers using javascript. The difference to your PHP-snippet approach is only that it is executed client-side, at the user's view of the application. So, you can only leak data that the current user is knowing, and you can only compromise the application with the rights of the current user (and his credentials).

However, it would be more difficult to detect javascript injections (which can also happen clientside or during the transfer) than malicious PHP snippets.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. And does is mean that Javascript on some webpage can, on client execution, 'report itself' to developer / send info about URL that resides on and request/client IP?

Comment: Yes. Google "XSS injection" - an attack scenario every developer of web applications which allow any user-generated data should be aware of.

Comment: Uh, just reporting itself, with URL and client IP, is done in a large scale by e.g. [Google's CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/) and any other external script inclusion…